# EPPlus - Create and validate digital signature

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

is it possible to add a digital signature to an excel document with EPPlus and validate a digital signature of an existing excel document?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can go with a detached signature.

You can **create a signature** using the following code:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath, password);

byte[] signature;

using (RSA rsa = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey())
{
    signature = rsa.SignData(data, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
}
```

where data is a byte array

Then store it to an external file

For **validating the signature** you need your xlsx file and the external signature file.

Then you can verify the signature using the following code

```
X509Certificate2 publicCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath);

var valid = false;
using (RSA rsa = publicCertificate.GetRSAPublicKey())
{
    valid = rsa.VerifyData(fileData, signatureData, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
}
```

where fileData is a byte array of your xlsx file and signatureData is a byte array of your signature file

Tell me if it worked =)

Comment: My challenge is to generate a signed excel document and send it to a person, so they can check it and send it to a third party.
It should be as simple as possible for the user :)

Comment: Then you can only do it by using the integrated excel tools

Comment: I think I found a solution. This object seems to be what I am looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.signatures?view=vsto-2017