# EPPlus - How to Remove Digital Signature

Tags: c#, excel, certificate, digital-signature, epplus

I would like to remove a [digital signature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01) from a VBA signed excel macro file. However when I look at EPPlus's library I see that the "Signature" property is read-only, and setting the Certificate as null doesn't seem to remove it, only invalidates the signature in the file:

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(fiNew))
{
    xlPackage.Workbook.VbaProject.Signature.Certificate = null;
    xlPackage.Save();
}
```

Calling the dispose method doesn't work either, errors out on the save. Does anybody know how to do this in EPPlus?

Comment: Have you tries `xlPackage.Workbook.VbaProject.Signature = null`?

Comment: @DanielFisherlennybacon That code will not build(EPPlus version 4). Signature only has a get method, no setter.

Comment: Looking at the [sources](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/blob/develop/src/EPPlus/Vba/ExcelVBASignature.cs) just provide a certificate without a private key - see line 137.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/blob/develop/src/EPPlus/Vba/ExcelVBASignature.cs) just provide a certificate without a private key - see line 137.

```cs
        internal void Save(ExcelVbaProject proj)
        {
            if (Certificate == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (Certificate.HasPrivateKey==false)    //No signature. Remove any Signature part
```

You could for example just use the first certificate in the `Trusted Root Certificate Authorities`, which have no keys, as long as you are not running on a root certificate authority or somebody improted a PFX by accident... so we filter for that too:

[image]

Here is some code to read from the `Trusted Root Certificate Authorities` store:

```cs
using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)) {
  store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
  var someCertWithoutPrivateKey = 
    store.Certificates
      .Cast<X509Certificate2>()
      .Where(c => !c.HasPrivateKey)
      .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Interesting, well the "HasPrivateKey" property only has a get method so your going to need to create a entirely different cert without a private key, then somehow distribute that with your application, and sign the VBA file with this new cert, maybe something like the following [like the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55511086/2912011), that seems pretty heavy handed but I suppose in theory that would work, I'd have to do some testing to see if this actually does, still it's too bad there isn't an easier way to do this.